# Google Analytics - Different "Total Events" value when clicking the event category

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GA event tracking.
On the main "top events" screen I see that there were ~250k events for that category.

BUT

When I click on the event category, the Total Events value changes to nearly half of the original amount! How come? And what does that mean?

Here's a screen shot of before and after clicking the event category.
[image: before and after clicking]
I can provide full screen shots if that's important.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at different data sets here, that's why the information is different. The first one is your Event Category, and it's 249204 events for that category. The second one is the event action of that category.

One event category however could have different numbers of event actions, and as it's showed on your screenshot - the 112576 events are events in this category, with one given action (you can see below the number 112K - 38.32% of the 249K, which means - the given **event action** had fired 112K times, and it's 38% of all events in the same **event category**.

**TL;DR: You are comparing Event Category vs Event Action, and they may or may not be different numbers, depending on your event tracking setup.**

Comment: If I understand correctly - these numbers mean that this particular event was fired 136,628 with a category but with no action?

Comment: I'll need to check the full screenshot to give you correct answer, but yes, by the screenshot - There were 249204 events from that event category, and 136628 didn't had event action setted up (that's why it shows you only the 112576 events with event action)... so, yes :)